# Unable to click the element. Error: no such element: Unable to locate element:

Tags: selenium

I am practicing on flipkart.com. i am unable to click the product after the search result. The xpath is correct. I tried using scroll function,visible, find by partial linktext, wait, sleep still i am unable to do. Please find the below code.

```
package Flipkart;

import org.openqa.selenium.By; import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class TC2 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException
    {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Chrome\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.flipkart.com/");
        driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys("Bag");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[1]/div/header/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/form/div/div[2]/button")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='container']/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/a[2]")).click();
    } 
}

  Error:
    Starting ChromeDriver 2.25.426923 (0390b88869384d6eb0d5d09729679f934aab9eed) on port 17575
    Only local connections are allowed.
    Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":".//*[@id='container']/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/a[2]"}
      (Session info: chrome=58.0.3029.81)
      (Driver info: chromedriver=2.25.426923 (0390b88869384d6eb0d5d09729679f934aab9eed),platform=Windows NT 10.0.14393 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
    Command duration or timeout: 76 milliseconds
    For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
    Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
    System info: host: 'D90T0CQ1', ip: '192.168.162.83', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_102'
    Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
    Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, mobileEmulationEnabled=false, networkConnectionEnabled=false, chrome={chromedriverVersion=2.25.426923 (0390b88869384d6eb0d5d09729679f934aab9eed), userDataDir=C:\Users\SALUNK~1\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir12552_16506}, takesHeapSnapshot=true, pageLoadStrategy=normal, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, hasTouchScreen=false, version=58.0.3029.81, platform=XP, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true, acceptSslCerts=true, locationContextEnabled=true, webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true}]
    Session ID: a8c3432c9b1e8cce3365db9407fc310f
    *** Element info: {Using=xpath, value=.//*[@id='container']/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/a[2]}
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:206)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:158)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:678)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:363)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementByXPath(RemoteWebDriver.java:500)
        at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByXPath.findElement(By.java:361)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:355)
        at Flipkart.TC2.main(TC2.java:15)
```

Comment: Format the code correctly. Error log shows selenium in not able to identify the element which is in line 15. Make sure the identifier is correct and static and handle accordingly

Comment: The element is dynamic so the xpath changes everytime, so i am unable to locate the exact element by xpath or customize xpath. could you please help to resolve this issue.

Comment: can you post the attributes of the dynamic varying element?

Comment: <a class="_2cLu-l" title="Puma PUMA Zipper Backpack 26 L Laptop Backpack" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href="/puma-zipper-backpack-26-l-laptop/p/itmesgfskwvwcwrr?pid=BKPESGFS4JUKMTFS&srno=s_1_1&otracker=search&lid=LSTBKPESGFS4JUKMTFSHJHGVM&qH=d3ab3d5184fe9b1b">Puma PUMA Zipper Backpack 26 L Laptop Backpack</a>

Comment: driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@title='Puma PUMA Zipper Backpack 26 L Laptop Backpack']")).click();

Comment: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//a[@title='Puma PUMA Zipper Backpack 26 L Laptop Backpack']"}

Comment: can you try using linktext... driver.findElement(By.linkText("Skybags Pixel Plus 03 30 L Backpack")).click();

Comment: i tried using all the locators still facing the same issue.

Comment: When I tried your code, It clicked on "Skybags Pixel Plus 03 30 L Backpack  (Grey)", Did you code to click that or any other?

Comment: Chandra could you please share the code you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the Answer to your Question:

I don't see any such errors/issues in your code. A few words about the solution:

1. Chrome browser sometimes doesn't opens `maximized` so you need to `maximize` the Chrome browser using `ChromeOptions` class.
2. If the browser is not maximized certain elements doesn't appers within the [Viewport](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp) and and may throw `NoSuchElementException`
3. Add the argument to disable the infobars through `ChromeOptions` class.
4. Your `xpath` looks vulnerable to me, try to construct logical `xpath` for the elements on the `HTML DOM`.
5. Your own code works at my end with some simple tweaks which opens the Chrome 
   Browser, navigates to the URL `https://www.flipkart.com/`, searches for `Bag`, clicks on `Skybags Pixel Plus 03 30 L Backpack` and `Skybags Pixel Plus 03 30 L Backpack  (Grey)` is opened in a new tab.
6. Here is the modified code block:

   ```
   System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\your_directory\\chromedriver.exe");
   ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
   options.addArguments("start-maximized");
   options.addArguments("disable-infobars");
   WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
   driver.get("https://www.flipkart.com/");
   driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys("Bag");
   driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[1]/div/header/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/form/div/div[2]/button")).click();
   driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='container']/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/a[2]")).click();
   ```

Let me know if this Answers your Question.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the same lines of code which you have mentioned and things work for me. Maybe you should try again.

Please try to use small **xpath**:

**Suggestion:**

Replace Xpath: **html/body/div[1]/div/header/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/form/div/div[2]/button** with the different Xpath:
                                        **//form[@action="/search"]/div/div[2]/button**

You should use relative path instead of absolute path because if there are any changes made in the path of the element then that XPath gets failed.

Comment: The search button is functioning, i am unable to select the bag

Comment: try using the concepts of: https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_axes.asp in your locators

Answer (score 0):

Final solution and I can't suggest more than this,

```
//openChromeBrowser();
    driver.get("https://www.flipkart.com/");
    driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys("Bag");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//form[@action='/search']/div/div[2]/button")).click();
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    driver.findElement(By.linkText("Puma PUMA Zipper Backpack 26 L Laptop Backpack")).click();
```

1> Give some wait time and it works
2> Use LinkText for locators for any of the item shown.

And follow what @Monika Singhal has said for quick and efficient results in Automation.

Comment: Config Details : Chrome Version 58.0.3029.110 (64-bit)
Selenium V - 3.0.1
Chrome Driver V - 2.29.41

Answer (score 0):

I got the same exception and added implicitly wait. It is working fine now. The code

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\lib\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.get("https://www.flipkart.com/");
    driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys("Bag");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[1]/div/header/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/form/div/div[2]/button")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='_2cLu-l']")).click();`
```

Comment: //*[@class='_2cLu-l'] - This is not specific to a particular item in the list,pl check